# Override box-shadow variables only work with !important flag

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to remove all box-shadows from my theme. This works with this code:

```
$btn-active-box-shadow: none !important;
$input-box-shadow: none !important;
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow: none !important;
```

Without the important flag it does not work.

My import is:

```
// Override Boostrap variables
@import "variables";

// Import Bootstrap source files
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

My import content:

```
* KM Websolutions Projects
* @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 KM Websolutions
* @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
*/
// Override bootstrap variables
/* stylelint-disable */
$font-size-base:              1rem; // Assumes the browser default, typically `16px`
$font-size-lg:                ($font-size-base * 1.25);
$font-size-md:                ($font-size-base * .875);
$font-size-sm:                ($font-size-base * .8);

$btn-active-box-shadow: none !important;
$input-box-shadow: none !important;
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow: none !important;

// Own variables
$smartgreen: #8bc906;
$facebookblue: #4267b2;
/* stylelint-enable */
```

Comment: Most likely the order of the SASS imports/overrides. Can you post all of the relevant SASS you're using?

Comment: I go the recommended way, means my overrides first and then the bootstrap variables (the other way it doesn't work. I have tested this). I can override ohter bootstrap variables without problems and without !important.